# Picture with Menu

Tags: html, css

I want to have this menu inside my image. I have trouble, my image is not with the menu.The menu will be up or down from my image. I want to place my menu in the image.I am working on My Microsoft web expression.

```
<ul>
<li><a>Home  </a></li>
<li><a>About</a>
<ul>
<li><a>Our Team </a></li>
<li><a>Our Team </a></li>
<li><a>Our Team </a></li>
<li><a>Our Team </a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a>things to do </a>
<ul>
<li><a> Team </a></li>
<li><a> Team </a></li>
<li><a> Team </a></li>
<li><a> Team </a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a>contact</a>
<ul>
<li><a>serTeam </a></li>
<li><a>serteam </a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a>News</a></li>
</ul>
```

the .css part of my code

```
ul {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
list-style: none;
}
ul li {
float: left;
width: 200px;
height: 40px;
background-color: black;
opacity: .8;
line-height: 40px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
}
ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
display: block;
}
ul li a:hover {
background-color: green;
}
ul li ul li {
display: none;
}
ul li.hover ul li {
display: block;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do - can you attach a quick sketch of what you want to see?

Comment: @freefall hi https://ibb.co/Wg3bPVF I want when I go with my mouse to the "About" to show the things I have write. But with the background picture I have add it doesn't work . The things I refer from About is the first list {<li><a>Our Team </a></li>
<li><a>Our Team </a></li>
<li><a>Our Team </a></li>
<li><a>Our Team </a></li> }

Comment: Can you edit your post to add your full code please? If you have the background image included via CSS it should work already